# Linux security books

Tags: linux, professional-education

I am trying to find an updated book (preferably from 2012-2013) that can cover linux security aspects comprehensively. I searched on Amazon and found that most Linux security books are from back in 2001. The one I thought had practical contents (atleast from its table of contents) was [Linux Security By Craig Hunt](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/078212741X)

Can anyone suggest what other, more updated & comprehensive, linux security books are out there ?

Comment: Any particular topic you are interested in? Security is a broad field. Good books are usually only covering a particular topic, e.g. SELinux or Apache or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend "[Network and System Security, Second Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/012416689X)" which include several topics like unix and network security.